# Excel VBA loop not moving to next row

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm so stuck.  I can't figure why I can't get this simple loop to work and I still need to expand once I've got part 1 complete.  My loop won't move to next i to continue search.

```
Sub TryThis()

Dim Purch As String
Dim Sales As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Purch = "PURCHASES"
Sales = "SALES"

finalrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A12000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To finalrow
If Cells(i, 1) = Purch Then
  Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Copy
  Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
  Range("A300").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
End If

Next i

Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

I'm running on empty so I know I'm missing something simple.  In the end, what I'm trying to do is loop through rows and if the row, column A has "Purchases", or "Sales", copy that row to sheet 2.

Ideally, I'd like to have sales show in column C in sheet 2 and purchases in column b, but I'll deal with that later,  just trying to get going and must be thinking so hard I'm missing the simple answer.

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `finalrow`? If it is less than 6, the loop will not be executed. Also it is best to be explicit about what sheet you're working with. Using Cells and Range without explicitly specifying the sheet to use opens you up to unexpected results.

Comment: Did you mean `finalrow =Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A12000").Row` or `finalrow = 12000`? The way you have it,  `finalrow` is being set to a value of 1.

Comment: Final row in this dump of data is 403. There will usually be at least 400 rows every time I go to run this.

Comment: Miles, My brain is still not working right on this.  It's been a while since I've written VBA in excel.  If I want to use "End(xlUp)" to find my last row, am I using the correct syntax.  What should I have there to get my final row to, in this case be equal to row 403?

Comment: I just don't understand where the `A12000` comes in? Why not try something dynamic, like this:  `finalrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I could use that, just being lazy.  I'm still not getting my loop to move to the next row when searching.  It pulls the first row with purchases in it then never moves beyond that row.

Comment: Is Sheet1 active when you run the macro?

Comment: So, everyone has been asking about "Finalrow".  No matter what I change it to, the loop only finds the first value and never continues the search in column A for the variable I'm looking for.  THIS IS Where I'm stuck.  I can change final row to everyone's suggestion and my problem still remains.                                     The question I need to resolve is why the loop never looks to the next row after the first row it looks at which is row 6 .

Comment: And everyone is explaining that if your code finds the `finalrow` with a value of  1.  If you are looping from 6 to 1, your loop will end after 1 iteration.

Comment: Step through your code. You're the only one who can see your data - we are in the dark. And answer the very first question please.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value being assigned to finalrow.

Without having your file available, this is difficult to diagnose.  I'm unable to find any obvious errors in your code, so I'll go based on experience.

There are quite a few ways to determine what the final row of a spreadsheet is.  You're using my favorite, but it has a couple pitfalls:

1. Column A could be blank.  I usually encounter this when using data pasted from another sheet or an SQL query, but this would be project specific.
2. Column A could extend beyond 12000 rows.  I usually encounter this when I've populated column A with a formula and "autofilled" too far down.  "End(xlUp)" would then go to "A1".

To (usually) get around either of these issues, I always use the max possible row as a starting point; A65563 for Office 2010 or earlier, or A1048576 for anything after that.  It doesn't take any longer to process, and gets more consistent results.

Comment: It's nice everyone is talking about the final row issue, Its just I don't see what that has to do with my loop problem.  My loop only works on the first instance of the variable I'm searching for and never finds another.  There are about 100 purchases I need to strip out to another worksheet.  So, why does the loop not move beyond the first instance it finds.  I have changed the final row several times to use everyone's suggestion there.  It still does not solve my problem.

Comment: @ErikOtterholt - The first time the For loop is encountered, "i" is explicitly set to 6.  Once the Next line is hit, it compares "i" to "finalrow".  If "finalrow" is 6 or less, it leaves the loop.  Easiest way to test this would be to change the For line to "i = 6 to 10".  If it gets past 6, then your definition of "finalrow" is the problem.

Comment: First, you just use purchase to compare. The second you must check your cells content in column a, please try to trim them and make them to be upper case

Comment: Oh, I'm so tired, It's funny how lack of sleep makes you miss the obvious. I was using break points on my code and my instances of Purchases were several rows apart. I would only hit F5 3 or 4 times which never took me to the next row of data. My code worked from the start. I feel so stupid. Trying to troubleshoot something and not recognizing my error in not letting the code get to the next row. Oh, I need sleep.

Thanks everyone